# Azure ML static Endpoint with dynamic model

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-machine-learning-service, mlops

Is it possible to deploy an endpoint with the latest model on Azure ML? So, I have a CICD Pipeline on Azure DevOps that will generate and evaluate a new model with the latest model and it will Register a model with a better one. But, the problem is when I try to deploy the endpoint, it only can attach a specific model, not the best model. So, if I want to deploy a new one, it will generate a new endpoint link.

So my question is, is it possible to deploy an endpoint with the newest model without changing its URL REST endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

**Azure static ML endpoint service is in public preview which means there is no SLA applicable.**

You can actually deploy the endpoint with the newest model without changing its URL REST endpoint, but you need to specify the model because it won't choose the best by itself.

But make sure, **Endpoint names need to be unique at the Azure region level. For example, there can be only one endpoint with the name my-endpoint in westus2.**

Refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-deploy-with-rest